# HTML5 Canvas : How do I merge 2 canvas into 1 (of which 1 is draggable)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, angularjs-directive, html5-canvas

I have changed 2 images into 2 different canvas (Main Image Canvas & Logo Canvas).
One of the canvas (Logo canvas) is made draggable over another canvas (Main Image canvas). Once the Logo is moved and placed, I want to combine both the Canvas into one single canvas (image) and send the toDataURL(); output to the server. How do I achieve this ?

Edit:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="clearfix" style="position: relative;">
        <div creativecanvasdirective style="position: absolute; z-index: 1"></div>
        <div logocanvasdirective style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; cursor: move;"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
app.directive('creativecanvasdirective',['$rootScope','$templateRequest','$compile', function($rootScope,$templateRequest,$compile) {
    return {
        template: "<canvas id='creative' width='500' height='500'/>",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var creative_canvas = document.getElementById('creative'),
            creative_context = creative_canvas.getContext('2d');

            make_creative();

            function make_creative()
            {
                creativeimage = new Image();
                creativeimage.src = scope.creative_image;
                creativeimage.onload = function() {
                    creative_context.drawImage(creativeimage, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            scope.$watch('creative_image', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    make_creative();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);

app.directive('logocanvasdirective',['$rootScope','$templateRequest','$compile', function($rootScope,$templateRequest,$compile) {
    return {
        template: "<canvas id='logo' width='500' height='500'/>",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('logo'),
            logo_context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            make_logo();

            function make_logo()
            {
                logoimage = new Image();
                logoimage.src = scope.brand_logo; // scope variable defined in controller
                logoimage.onload = function() {
                    logo_context.drawImage(logoimage, 20, 20);
                }
            }
            scope.$watch('brand_logo', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    make_logo();

                    var canvasOffset=$("#logo").offset();
                    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
                    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
                    var canvasWidth=canvas.width;
                    var canvasHeight=canvas.height;
                    var isDragging=false;

                    function handleMouseDown(e){
                        canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
                        canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
                        // set the drag flag
                        isDragging=true;
                    }

                    function handleMouseUp(e){
                        canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
                        canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
                        // clear the drag flag
                        isDragging=false;
                    }

                    function handleMouseOut(e){
                        canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
                        canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
                        // user has left the canvas, so clear the drag flag
                        isDragging=false;
                    }

                    function handleMouseMove(e){
                        canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
                        canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
                        // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
                        if(isDragging){
                            logo_context.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
                            logo_context.drawImage(logoimage,canMouseX,canMouseY+canvasHeight/4);
                        }
                    }

                    $("#logo").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
                    $("#logo").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
                    $("#logo").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
                    $("#logo").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now how do I combine these two canvas into single canvas and send it to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) (you can pass in the canvas element directly) to draw the Logo Canvas onto the Main Canvas, and then just use `toDataURL` on the Main Canvas to output it.

Or if you want to preserve the Main Canvas, you can create another canvas and draw onto it the Main Canvas, and then the Logo Canvas.

---

UPDATE

Here is the code (sorry for long data sources - tainted canvas): https://jsfiddle.net/xmmo9m3t/

```js
var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
 var bgctx = bg.getContext('2d');
 bgctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('bgimg'), 0, 0);
 
 var canvas = document.getElementById('logo');
 var logo_context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 make_logo();

 function make_logo() {
   logoimage = document.getElementById('logoimg');
   logoimage.onload = function() {
     logo_context.drawImage(logoimage, 0, 0);
   }
 }
 var canvasOffset = $("#logo").offset();
 var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
 var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
 var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
 var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
 var isDragging = false;

 function handleMouseDown(e) {
   canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
   canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
   // set the drag flag
   isDragging = true;
 }

 function handleMouseUp(e) {
   canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
   canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
   // clear the drag flag
   isDragging = false;
 }

 function handleMouseOut(e) {
   canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
   canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
   // user has left the canvas, so clear the drag flag
   isDragging = false;
 }

 function handleMouseMove(e) {
   canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
   canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
   // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
   if (isDragging) {
     logo_context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
     logo_context.drawImage(logoimage, canMouseX, canMouseY + canvasHeight / 4);
   }
 }

 $("#logo").mousedown(function(e) {
   handleMouseDown(e);
 });
 $("#logo").mousemove(function(e) {
   handleMouseMove(e);
 });
 $("#logo").mouseup(function(e) {
   handleMouseUp(e);
 });
 $("#logo").mouseout(function(e) {
   handleMouseOut(e);
 });
 
 function output() {
  bgctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    document.write("<p>IMG below:</p><img src='" + bg.toDataURL() + "' />");
 }
```

```css
canvas {position: absolute}
img {max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" id="bgimg">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" id="logoimg">
<button onclick="output()">OUTPUT</button><br>
<canvas id="bg" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
<canvas id="logo" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
<img id="result">
```

Comment: Seems good :)

But still facing problem calling the output function.
Since, both the canvas are through directive.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue as long as you properly refer them. What kind of problem are you having?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103200/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-shomz).